# execute a shell script from different folder in Python

Tags: python, bash

I'm not a pythonist, just need to fix some script.
So I'm want to run some Bash shell script that placed not in the same folder as the Python script but in one of its subfolder.

So that what I did:

```python
app_path = os.getcwd()
path = app_path + os.path.sep + "some/subfolder"
retval = subprocess.call(["script.sh"], cwd=path)
```

Unfortunately I get an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script.sh'

Adding `shell=True` doesn't help but the error changes to:

> /bin/sh: 1: script.sh: not found

The error looks strange for me especially since my current shell is `/bin/bash`

```console
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

So far I've found only this ugly workaround:

```python
app_path = os.getcwd()
path = app_path + os.path.sep + "some/subfolder"
os.chdir(path)
retval = subprocess.call(["./script.sh"], shell=True)
```

but it seems to me an absolute ugliness.

What I do wrong? How can I execute an external bash script from a Python one?

Comment: `os.getcwd()` and the script folder are two different entities. You might want to parse `__file__` to get the latter

Comment: In your first example change `script.sh` to `./script.sh`.

Comment: @Marat, I run the script from the command line so that probably will be the same.

Comment: It won't be the same unless `.` is on your PATH, and putting `.` on your PATH is considered is pretty bad practice from a security perspective. So it ought not be the same.

Comment: Just did a bunch of tests to finally delete my answer, because `subprocess.call(["/.script.sh"], cwd=path)` works for me.

Comment: Note that you should be able to use `subprocess.call(['./some/subfolder/script.sh'])` if your script is correctly written; if it doesn't work right unless its cwd is the same as its source directory, that's a bug in the shell script itself, not a bug in how you start it from Python. [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) may be relevant if you're going to try to fix said script.

Comment: BTW, note that `echo $SHELL` has nothing at all to do with how `shell=True` behaves. `shell=True` **always** uses `/bin/sh` if you're on a UNIX platform and don't explicitly override it with a different executable, no matter what your `SHELL` variable is. Whereas if you don't set `shell=True` there's no shell used at all, except perhaps one the target executable asks the OS to start for it via its shebang (which is part of why using shebangs on your scripts is critical!).

Comment: I think the problem is you are expecting `subprocess.call(["script.sh"], cwd=path)` to cwd into the dir and then find `script.sh` but I think what actually happens is the subprocess.call has to first find the script based on current working dir, then it changes the working dir context that that script runs in.  So at minimum you need `subprocess.call([path + "script.sh"])` and then whether you also need `cwd=path` as well depends on behaviour of script.sh

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `shell=True`. You don't need `os.path.join()`.

Either fix your bash script so it doesn't assume that its current working directory is the same as the location of its source code, so you can use:

```
retval = subprocess.call(["./some/subfolder/script.sh"])
```

...or use:

```
retval = subprocess.call(["./script.sh"], cwd='./some/subfolder')
```

...making sure that your script is executable (starts with a shebang, has `+x` permissions set).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the scripts to be invoked using a relative path as it depends on how your app is started and from where, so if your scripts are in a know directory (*this can come from a configuration file, env or a system known location*):

```
os.environ['PATH'] += f'{os.pathsep}/path/to/my/scripts'
...
p = subprocess.run(['script1.sh'], env=os.environ)
...
p = subprocess.run(['script2.sh'], env=os.environ)
```

Also, I would use `run` instead of `call` in new code.

If you never ever are going to pass arguments you can also use

```
p = subprocess.run('script2.sh', env=os.environ)
```

**PS:** All fixes in @CharlesDuffy answer are also needed.